# The sound stopped when press lock button

Tags: java, android

I had the Android App which play sound when specific times , I did my
code well but when I locked the screen the sound isnot play , I
checked my code and I find that the code that I added when user press
lock button is the reason of the problem .How to solve this issue ?

```
       @Override
   protected void onPause() {
          Player.stopAzan();
          finish();
          super.onPause();
   }
```

Comment: What would you like to do? Do you want to play sound in background?

Comment: You are finishing activity in onPause() which is surely called on lock button pressed. How would it play in background when context has been destroyed?

Comment: @Adnan not only context is destroyed, but the player is intentionally stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using a service? Services are basically same that activities but they run in background and have no content view if I get them right :D

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is impossible since when the screen is locked, the Activity is stopped.
You either decide if want to play in background or not, because when the screen is locked, the Activity goes background.

- If you don't need to play in background then you're good to go, just remove the finish() method.
- If you do need to play the music in background, use a Service to start and stop player based on Intents passed from Activity user controls.